# record update into table logs

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I have 3 tables tasks , task_notes and taskLog

I want to ask what is the best way to record logs when user enter new notes in task_notes table

Comment: I don't know, but what should happen according to your requirements? If you just `INSERT` a row into task_notes then insert it as you usually do, but if you need something else to happen then you should explain what and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger on the table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx